next.js image alias and Image component
All my other alias (components...) are ok but not the one below. What is the right way to do that ?
import Image from 'next/image';
import heroImage from '@images/hero.jpg'; // Using the alias

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Image
      src={heroImage}
      alt="Hero Image"
      width={800}
      height={600}
    />
  );
}

